# How to place EditText and ImageButton correctly on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-imagebutton

I have this layout :

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/et_word"
                android:drawableBottom="@color/bottomcolor"/>

            <!--android:ems="14" -->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

This layout looks like this : 
[image]

How can I change my current code so that the imagebutton can be displayed? Thanks.

EDIT : 
Now it looks like this : [image]

Comment: where do you want your button to be placed ?

Comment: @fandro Next to edittext, on the right.

Comment: the width of editText should not be fill_parent, it should be wrap_content

Comment: @jason you can check my answer

Comment: I saw that you updated the question. Is still there a problem?

Comment: @IulianPopescu I added what you said and I added the result. It's how it looks like now.

Comment: And this is what you want, right?

Comment: @IulianPopescu No, it's not what I want, it's not correct. The edittext is not filling all remaining space.. There is still space on the right.

Comment: I guess that your image has a little space and this is why you see that white space. If you change the background color to something different than white for imageButton you'll be able to see that the editText fills all the remaining space.

Comment: @IulianPopescu You are right. Can you tell me how I can get rid of that extra white space on the right? Thank you

Comment: You could add a negative padding to the imageButton to move it a little to the left, but the correct way is to edit the image and remove that space (I don't know to much about image editing so I can't help you here). Also, if everything is fixed, please accept the answer since it can help others :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add for the editText

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: I did what you said, but edittext is not filling all the remaining space.

Comment: Well, it should. Can you please update the xml and the result?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_word"
            android:drawableBottom="@color/bottomcolor"/>

        <!--android:ems="14" -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:orientation="vertical">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:paddingRight="10dp">

               <EditText
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                   android:inputType="text"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/et_word"
                   android:drawableBottom="@color/bottomcolor"/>

               <!--android:ems="14" -->

               <ImageButton
                   android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:src="@drawable/pink"
                   android:background="@color/white"
                   android:paddingRight="0dp"
                   android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                   android:paddingTop="0dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                   />

           </LinearLayout>


       </LinearLayout>
```

Output will be look like: [image: this]

Comment: there is no layout_weight for ImageButton, so this will not work. And if you have a weight, the width should be set to fill_parent, not wrap_content...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs this is working correctly..i have added output screen shot. you can take a look

Answer (score 2):

I placed, colors, and image just to do it, replace by yours and it should work :
Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_word"
            android:drawableBottom="@color/colorAccent"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    <!--android:ems="14" -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_getir"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit :
You can play with the values of layout_weight to give more space to your edit text, the total must be equals to 1, it's why I put 0.5 and 0.5

Answer (score 0):

change the android:layout_width="fill_parent" to some value if you want to place the button to right or left if you want it down or above the edittext change the orientation